# Printing geographical centroid coordinates of georeferenced image in CSV file

Tags: raster, gdal, csv, georeferencing, contour

I am trying to print the centroids of the circular contours from the image.
[image]

The image is already georeferenced using GDAL with ESRI 102025 and I tried to extract the points in terms of the geographical coordinates so that I can export them into QGIS through the following code,

```py
def geopointextract(tiffile, outputcsv, 5):
  #csv file fields
  fields =[ "Filename", 'Centroid X', 'Centroid Y']
  filename = outputcsv
  #Reading the Input Image
  img = gdal.Open(tiffile)
  img=np.array(img.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,120,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5)) #tunable
  opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)
  # Extracting the contours
  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:   
  # creating a csv writer object   
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)   
# writing the fields   
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)   
    for c in contours:
  # calculate moments for each contour
     M = cv2.moments(c)
  # calculate x,y coordinate of center
     cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
     cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
     rows = [[tiffile, cX, cY]]  
# writing the data rows of centroids  
     csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

This extracts centroids of these masks (I took an example mask from an another image),
[image]

The output I got was,
[image: ![enter image description here]

The coordinates are clearly not Geographical coordinates of Pakistan in ESRI: 102025. How can I extract the geographical coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go from image coordinates to geographic coordinates, get the geotransform using `img.GetGeoTransform()`, then the transform is as follows:

```
gt = img.GetGeoTransform()

x_pixel = cX
y_line = cY

x_geo = gt[0] + x_pixel * gt[1] + y_line * gt[2]
y_geo = gt[3] + x_pixel * gt[4] + y_line * gt[5]
```

Source: https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html#transformation-from-image-coordinate-space-to-georeferenced-coordinate-space